# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

1. Source code

PHP file

```
<?php
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm_password = $_POST['confirm-password'];
if (!empty($Username) || !empty($email) ||  !empty($password) || !empty($confirm_password))
{
  $host = 'localhost';
  $username = 'root';
  $pass = '';
  $db = 'pharmacy';
  $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $pass, $db);
  if(mysqli_connect_error())
  {
    die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_error().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  else
  {
    $INSERT = "INSERT INTO `signup`(`Username`, `email`, `password`, `confirm_password`) VALUES 
    (?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$Username,$email,$password,$confirm_password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($Username,$email,$password,$confirm_password);
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;
    if($rnum == 0)
    {
      $stmt->close();
      header("location: /E_Commerce/html/login.php");
    }
    else {
      alert("All fields are required");
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt1->close();
    $conn->close();
  }
}
else {
  echo "All fields are required..";
  die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you include the actual error message as well as show which line the error is being shown on.

Comment: `INSERT` statements don't have any results to return, so `bind_result` may fail.

Comment: Before moving on to the error, why will you store confirm password in the database?